# View multiple uploading image inline in placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Before uploading multiple images via html form, I want to view them all inline such as in a div I called as a placeholder.

The multiple uploding method is by generating new `browse` botton with javascript. So when one botton is clicked, new botton will be shown up.

**`Here is the js code that generates new bottons:`**

```
$(function(){
$('#image1').on('click',function(){
                var r= $('<input type="file" name="image2" id="image2"/>')
            .on('click',function(){
                var r= $('<input type="file" value="new button" name="third-image" id="third-image"/>')
            .on('click',function(){
                var r= $('<input type="file" value="new button" name="fourth-image" id="fourth-image"/>');
    $("form").append(r);
});;
    $("form").append(r);
});
    $("form").append(r);
});
});
```

**`Here is the js code that will view the uploading image`**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#image1").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function readURL1(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah1').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#image2").change(function(){
    readURL1(this);
});
```

**`Here is my html form`**

```
    <form id="formulir" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="config-template-ecomerce.php">
    title-file<input  name="title" type="text" id="title"/><br>     
    color-one<input  name="color-one" type="text" id="color-one"/><br>

    <img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 100px;" /><br>

    image<input type="file" name="image1" id="image1"/><br>

    <img id="blah" src="#" style="width:300px;" />
    <img id="blah1" src="#" style="width:300px;" />
    <img id="blah2" src="#" style="width:300px;" />
    <img id="blah3" src="#" style="width:300px;" /><br>

    submit<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

The problem I encountered is, the js code to view the image only able to view one image. When I browse the second image, it can't be viewed.

[Here is my FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/682t5x6z/1/)

Comment: you have to call the change() function on each newly created input so that it shows the preview when it changes.

Comment: @dandavis How to do that? I am not so good in js. :(

Comment: call $(r).change(...) the same as you do for "#image2"

Comment: Can you show me how to do that. I am not very good in js.